# Mouse click on Task Switch Bar leads to desktop freeze

Tags: 22.04, freeze, desktop-environments

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with Xorg. After the following steps, graphics continue working and getting updated on the screen, but mouse button/keyboard presses yield no response, except for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>XXX</kbd> to switch sessions:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> → Task Switch Bar displays.
2. Click anywhere on Task Switch Bar → Desktop loses response.

Does anyone know the root cause/fix/workaround for this issue?